unknown error for last 24 hrs trying to run Debug
I am new to Google Scripts (should be obvious)
12:21:24 PM Error   An unknown error has
occurred, please try again later from any function
I don't know what to try, I lost all my triggers
anytime I've tried to close my project and open it again

It's just not Debug, if I try to Run from the scripts panel - same error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
